# How to have an anonymous return type in generic method?(like select method in linq)

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a generic method like :

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Select2<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

And a method call:

```
var r = Select2(p => new { FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName });
```

How can I set  TResult in my method call?
In linq when u use from select method u can see Tresult type as 'a
[image]
***Update***


For example I have my own orm and in select method I generate a T-Sql select query.with my method I want define specific column and get result from my specification.If I call method like

```
var r=Select2<Person,?>(p=> new{Name=p.FirstName ,Family=p.LastName})
```

I want that I generate a select with FirstName and LastName column and return type just has Name and Family Property

Comment: Please fix the code, what is the `(<TSource, TResult> selector)` syntax supposed to mean?

Comment: Also, just try to omit the generic type parameters for the call, see if the compiler will infer the types for you.

Comment: Short answer: no possible. If you need to pass in a `selector`, why don't call `selector` directly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen :I update my question.

Comment: there's a developer who worked hard on those "Show history" features that are present on stackoverflow sites. the bold, underlined, italic "Update" "Edit" messages are redundant and simply in the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the signature of the method is

```
TResult Select2<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

Simply writing `var r = Select2(p => new { ... })` doesn't work since the compiler can only infer the type of `TResult` and not the type of `TSource`.

Making the generic types explicit doesn't work either, because as you've seen you can't do that for the anonymous type.

What you can do is help the compiler by writing the lambda in a different way:

```
var r = Select2((Person p) => new { ... });
```

That way the compiler knows the type of `TSource` and can infer the type of `TResult`.

Comment: @Drik its worked.can you more explain about your code?how your code help to compiler to infer TResult?why in my code compiler con not infer TResult?

Comment: @M.Azad The problem is not that the compiler can't infer the type of `TResult`, it actually can. But for `Select2(p => new ...)` it can't infer the type of `TSource`.

Comment: @Drik I want to know is there any reason that it can't infer the type of TSource?

Comment: @M.Azad Given this code `Select2(p => new { FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName })`, what do you know about `p`? Not much at all except that it has a `FirstName` and a `LastName` property or field of unknown type. And that's not nearly enough for the compiler to infer the type.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I would prefer doing this, but you should use dynamics in this case:

```
IEnumrable<dynamic> Select2<TSource>(Func<TSource, dynamic> selector);
//method call
var r=Select2<Person>(p=> new{FullName=p.FirstName +" "+p.LastName});
```

If you look at micro ORMs like Dapper, you'll see that they also support method calls returning dynamic types.

Comment: @GertArnold - `dynamic` has its purposes for when types cannot be inferred, but in this case there is a simple strongly-typed solution - Dirk has posted it. So using `dynamic` is a weak solution that should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I agree. And I'll leave this here for the record.

Comment: @GertArnold - Fair enough. I appreciate your response.